# Sorting sub-lists into new sub-lists based on common first items

Tags: python, list, sorting

I have a large number of two-membered sub-lists that are members of a list called `mylist`:

```
mylist = [['AB001', 22100],
          ['AB001', 32935],
          ['XC013', 99834],
          ['VD126', 18884],
          ['AB001', 34439],
          ['XC013', 86701]]
```

I want to sort `mylist` into new sub-lists based on whether the sub-lists contain the same string as the first item. For example, this is what I am looking for my code to output:

```
newlist = [['AB001', 22100], ['AB001', 32935], ['AB001', 34439]],
          [['XC013', 99834], ['XC013', 86701]],
          [['VD126', 18884]]
```

Here is how I was trying to code this:

```
mylist = sorted(mylist)
newlist = []
for sublist in mylist:
    id = sublist[0]
if id == next.id:
    newlist.append(id)
print newlist
```

I was also trying to understand if `itertools.groupby()` was the correct tool for this problem. Can someone help me with this problem?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You were right about this being a job for [`groupby`](https://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby):

```
from itertools import groupby
from operator import itemgetter

mylist = [['AB001', 22100],
          ['AB001', 32935],
          ['XC013', 99834],
          ['VD126', 18884],
          ['AB001', 4439],
          ['XC013', 86701]]

print([list(value) for key, value in groupby(sorted(mylist), key=itemgetter(0))])
```

This will give you a list-of-lists, grouped by the first item in the sublist.

```
[[['AB001', 4439], ['AB001', 22100], ['AB001', 32935]], 
 [['VD126', 18884]], 
 [['XC013', 86701], ['XC013', 99834]]]
```

Comment: To save yourself an import, could you have just used lambda instead of itemgetter?

Comment: Yep, but it's slower, and this is what `itemgetter` is for.

Comment: Actually, you must sort by the same key your are grouping by so, `sorted(mylist)` should be replaced by `sorted(mylist, key=itemgetter(0)`.

Comment: @norok2 It depends if you care about the order of the values in the groups. If you don't care, you're right, you could use `itemgetter` again. But that detail isn't really important to the main point of the answer; the important part is the `groupby` with `itemgetter`. It so happens that in this case the default sort works fine.

Comment: It is not the order of the value in the groups at stakes, but rather the groups themselves. `sorted(mylist)` happen to work just fine here because `sorted(mylist, key=itemgetter(0))` will result in *the same grouping (modulo the order of the values in the groups)* in this case, but it is, in general, not true, e.g. `l = (1, 2, 3, 4)`, `def f(x): return x % 2` and `[list(v) for k, v in groupby(sorted(l), key=f)]` -> `[[1], [2], [3], [4]]` wrong; `[list(v) for k, v in groupby(sorted(l, key=f), key=f)]` -> `[[2, 4], [1, 3]]` correct.

Comment: @norok2 Yes, I agree. That's what I meant by "in this case the default sort works fine" in my previous comment.

Answer (score 3):

#### [`collections.defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict)

An `itertools.groupby` solution will incur O(*n* log *n*) cost since the input must be sorted *first*. You can a use `defaultdict` of lists for a guaranteed O(*n*) solution:

```
from collections import defaultdict

dd = defaultdict(list)
for item in mylist:
    dd[item[0]].append(item)

res = list(dd.values())

print(res)

[[['AB001', 22100], ['AB001', 32935], ['AB001', 34439]],
 [['XC013', 99834], ['XC013', 86701]],
 [['VD126', 18884]]]
```

Answer (score 2):

There are a number of alternatives to solve this problem:

```
def regroup_by_di(items, key=None):
    result = {}
    callable_key = callable(key)
    for item in items:
        key_value = key(item) if callable_key else item
        if key_value not in result:
            result[key_value] = []
        result[key_value].append(item)
    return result
```

```
import collections


def regroup_by_dd(items, key=None):
    result = collections.defaultdict(list)
    callable_key = callable(key)
    for item in items:
        result[key(item) if callable_key else item].append(item)
    return dict(result)  # to be in line with other solutions
```

```
def regroup_by_sd(items, key=None):
    result = {}
    callable_key = callable(key)
    for item in items:
        key_value = key(item) if callable_key else item
        result.setdefault(key_value, []).append(item)
    return result
```

```
import itertools


def regroup_by_it(items, key=None):
    seq = sorted(items, key=key)
    result = {
        key_value: list(group)
        for key_value, group in itertools.groupby(seq, key)}
    return result
```

```
def group_by(
        seq,
        key=None):
    items = iter(seq)
    try:
        item = next(items)
    except StopIteration:
        return
    else:
        callable_key = callable(key)
        last = key(item) if callable_key else item
        i = j = 0
        for i, item in enumerate(items, 1):
            current = key(item) if callable_key else item
            if last != current:
                yield last, seq[j:i]
                last = current
                j = i
        if i >= j:
            yield last, seq[j:i + 1]


def regroup_by_gb(items, key=None):
    return dict(group_by(sorted(items, key=key), key))
```

These can be divided into two categories:

1. loop through the input creating a `dict`-like structure (`regroup_by_di()`, `regroup_by_dd()`, `regroup_by_sd()`)
2. sorting the input and then use a [`uniq`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniq)-like function (e.g. [`itertools.groupby()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby)) (`regroup_by_it()`, `regroup_by_gb()`)

The first class of approaches has `O(n)` computational complexity, while the second class of approaches has `O(n log n)`.

All of the proposed approach require specifying a `key`.
For OP's problem, `operators.itemgetter(0)` or `lambda x: x[0]` would work. Additionally, to get OP's desired results one should get only the `list(dict.values())`, e.g.:

```
from operator import itemgetter


mylist = [['AB001', 22100],
          ['AB001', 32935],
          ['XC013', 99834],
          ['VD126', 18884],
          ['AB001', 4439],
          ['XC013', 86701]]


print(list(regroup_by_di(mylist, key=itemgetter(0)).values()))
# [[['AB001', 22100], ['AB001', 32935], ['AB001', 4439]], [['XC013', 99834], ['XC013', 86701]], [['VD126', 18884]]]
```

---

The timings come out as faster for all `dict`-based (1st class) solutions and slower for all `groupby`-based (2nd class) solutions.
Within the `dict`-based solutions, their performances will depend slightly on the *"collision rate"*, which is proportional to the number of times a new item will create a new object.
For higher collision rates, the `regroup_by_di()` may be the fastest, while for lower collision rates the `regroup_by_dd()` may be the fastest.

The benchmarks come out as follow:

- 0.1% collision rate (approx. 1000 elements per group)

[image: plot_0p1perc]

- 10% collision rate (approx. 10 elements per group)

[image: plot_10perc]

- 50% collision rate (approx. 2 elements per group)

[image: plot_50perc]

- 100% collision rate (approx. 1 element per group)

[image: plot_100perc]

(More details available [here](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1xX5oykmR2coOqFWDSChPlJvEG_vwh-Wy?usp=sharing).)

Answer (score 0):

## Without importing any packages:

- Build a dictionary and then get the values to a list

  - Use [`.get`](https://realpython.com/python-dicts/#dgetltkeygt-ltdefaultgt) to determine if a key exists, and return some specified value, `None` in this case, if the key is nonexistent.
  - [`dict.get`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get) defaults to `None`, so this method never raises a [KeyError](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#KeyError).

    - If `None` is a value in the dictionary, then change the default value returned by `.get`.

      - `test.get(t[0], 'something here')`
- Because: *sub-lists based on common first items*.

  - Add index 0 as the `key`, and then add the `list`, `t`, as the `dict` value.

```py
test = dict()
for t in mylist:
    if test.get(t[0]) == None:
        test[t[0]] = [t]
    else:
        test[t[0]].append(t)
        
final = list(test.values())

# print final results in

[[['AB001', 22100], ['AB001', 32935], ['AB001', 34439]],
 [['XC013', 99834], ['XC013', 86701]],
 [['VD126', 18884]]]
```